# How Can I Customize Number Sections RMarkdown?

Tags: r, lua, markdown, pandoc, bookdown

I've been working with R Markdown to generate Word document files. I'm using Bookdown as well. Automatic numbering works great so far, but it runs as 1, 1.1, and 1.1.1, but I want to customize the numbering to run like 1, 1.1, 1.1(a) or even with roman numerals.

I'm certain this is possible, but I've been wracking my brain trying to figure out how. I thought that maybe a Pandoc filter would be useful, but I didn't know where to start. I thought this might help,

https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/main/inst/rmarkdown/lua/number-sections.lua

but I was having some trouble understanding how I would modify that filter to work for what I need. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: What type of output? pdf? html? both?

Comment: @Kat, OP says they are generating Word documents.

Comment: Wow, I can read, really. Thanks, @Chris.

Comment: @Kat, docx file.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you're going to want to use [this](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/word-template.html) as a reference.

First, create a word document with Rmarkdown.You will probably want to put a little bit of everything in this initial file. It doesn't need to be meaningful content though. For example, R code—so you have the pandoc names for the styles of R code. Plots, headings, tables, all that jazz.

The important part is that Pandoc was used to create this file. This file will become your template. You will now set the styles you wished it would have used to begin with. For example, the numbered sections you are looking for.

I have a Mac; you may have Windows. To modify or create styles in MS Word (Home and Student 2021) for Mac, I go to the Home tab => the Styles Pane.

[image]

I find the styles in the default template to be the extreme opposite of aesthetically pleasing.

For this answer, I created a bit of an odd template just to show you how it works.

[image]

If I mark *Show styles guides* in the styles pane. I can see the template to features relationship. You can add as many or as few styles as you would like. However, I would suggest that you make sure that everything is assigned a style. For example, just because something looks the same as a heading, doesn't make it a heading.

[image]

This is my template for the RMarkdown, now. Here's the YAML of my RMD that I want to apply custom section numbering to.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "me"
date: '2022-05-17'
output: 
  word_document:
    reference_docx: "../_data/wordOutputTemplated.docx"
---
```

Here's the code I used.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Sections are nice

Some information might go here.

# Sections

Is it 12??

```{r doingIt}
sqrt(144)
```

## Subsections are blue

Blue enough

## Including Plots with Blue headings

### sub-subsections are red

You can also embed plots, for example:
````

##### Knitted with the template

Now when I knit this, I'll get the styles I preset in my reference document. You may have to play around a bit. For example, I removed the extra white space before paragraphs; now the heading is running into the R chunk.

[image]

Comment: I already have that going. There's an issue though. I need to have references and when I reference sections, it ignores the numbering of the reference doc.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how you referencing them, what you're expecting, and what you actually get?